# Marking an answer as favorite

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favoriting an answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/favoriting-an-answer)

Is there a way to mark an answer as "favorite"?

I am aware there is a way to mark questions as favorites by using the star on the left side of the question. I think it would be a nice feature to have for answers as well.

Comment: This seems more suited for meta.stackoverflow.com, and sure enough, it's already status-declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star.  The authoritative (and unpopular) answer states that it is very unlikely to ever be implemented.

Comment: Where is the bang-head-at-wall-smiley when you need it ... (although I think that this is less of an issue in maths than on other sites, because the number of answers is usually sufficiently small that I can find it again if I star the question.

Comment: I'm marking this status-declined based on Jonas Meyer's comment. If you would like this feature, you can try asking on Meta.SO and feel out the water there.

Comment: @Willie, a late remark: I think there was no need preemptively tagging this "status-declined" - why not leave that to a developer?

Comment: A new version of this question is asked [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/favoriting-an-answer), given that we are now encouraged to ask for feature requests on the local metas (previously software improvements should be asked for at meta.SO), I will close this request as a duplicate of the new one.

Comment: The answer I linked to appears to have been deleted and replaced by another authoritative and unpopular one.  That or I am confused; I can't see deleted posts on meta.SO.